# how to initialize each thread with different value

Tags: java, multithreading

i need to create three thread with different data.i want that one thread value can not be affect to the other thread value but here one thread value modifying the other  thread variable value. i do not know how to do .

this is my sample class which is create the three thread and initialize variable with different value.

```
public class One {

public void processChange(final String  userdata)
{
    Two Thread1=null,Thread2=null,Thread3=null;
    data.put("type","one");
    Thread1=new Two(data);
    Thread1.setName("one");
    Thread1.start();

    data.put("type","two");
    Thread2=new Two(data);
    Thread2.setName("two");
    Thread2.start();

    data.put("type","three");
    Thread3=new Two(data);
    Thread3.setName("three");
    Thread3.start();    


}
}
```

The other class which is extends the Thread

```
 public class Two extends Thread {

JSONObject data;

public Two(JSONObject data) {
this.data=data;
}
public Two() {
}

public void run()
{
        log.debug(this.getName()+" and data is"+data.toString());
        sendData(data);
        log.debug("after running "+this.getName()+" and data is"+data.toString());  
}
 }
```

after execute this above code. last initialize jsonObject data value contain all threads.
i want that each thread having jsonOjbect data will be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this. You need to create different JSONObject's for each Thread.

```
JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject();
data1.put("type","one");
Thread1=new Two(data1);
Thread1.setName("one");
Thread1.start();

JSONObject data2 = new JSONObject();
data2.put("type","two");
Thread2=new Two(data2);
Thread2.setName("two");
Thread2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the same `data` object that is passed to all threads. You will need to create new objects for each thread, otherwise the `"type"` value would already be `"three"` for all the threads.

```
public void processChange(final String  userdata)
{
    Two Thread1=null,Thread2=null,Thread3=null;
    JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject(); //*** SEE NOTE
    data1.put("type","one");
    Thread1=new Two(data1);
    Thread1.setName("one");
    Thread1.start();

    JSONObject data2 = new JSONObject(); //*** SEE NOTE
    data2.put("type","two");
    Thread2=new Two(data2);
    Thread2.setName("two");
    Thread2.start();

    JSONObject data3 = new JSONObject(); //*** SEE NOTE
    data3.put("type","three");
    Thread3=new Two(data3);
    Thread3.setName("three");
    Thread3.start();    

    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm not sure what the real constructor is. It's probably best if you use a copy constructor *(if available)*: `new JSONObject(data);`

Answer (score 0):

There is a class called ThreadLocal in java which will solve your problem.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html